# How can I apply a theme/style to an Action android

Tags: android, coding-style, action, themes

In Android, how can I apply a style to an API action?

I am using the RingtoneManager.RINGTON_PICKER action to let the user select an alarm, and would like to apply the standard theme that the other child-activities use.

Does anyone know how I can apply a theme? The code I'm using to open the RINGTONE_PICKER is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
((Activity)mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, BackendConstant.RINGTONE_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are starting this intent you will release the control to another program/part of the OS and your control over it (as far as I know) will be near zero. I think changing the style of a system Dialog is impossible.